# get the sum of diagonals and anti diagonals 2D N*N matrix using numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Consider an N*N matrix. I select any element and then I want the sum of diagonals and antidiagonals passing through it using numpy.

For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0,   1,   2,   3,   4],
                  [5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
                  [10,  11,  12,  13,  14],
                  [15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
                  [20,  21,  22,  23,  24]])
```

For the number 8 it should return (2+8+14) + (4+8+12+16+20).

Thanks.

Comment: How is 2, 8 and 14 the diagonal of your matrix?
Edit: ah, I see the point now. The number you pick shall be the center where the two diagonals cross

Comment: Sorry my bad in explaining it, I select any element and then I get the diagonal and anti diagonal passing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.diag`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html). Suppose you select element `a[i, j]`. Then,

```
>>> diagonal = np.diag(a, j-i)
>>> antidiagonal = np.diag(a[:, ::-1], N-j-1-i)
>>> np.sum(diagonal) + np.sum(antidiagonal)
```

This works, because `j-i` is the number of columns *above* the diagonal entry `(i, i)`. So `np.diag(a, j-i)` correctly picks the diagonal corresponding to 8.

For the antidiagonal, I simply flip the array horizontally (by reversing the columns), and then run `np.diag` again. But now, the new column index is `N-j-1`, while the row index remains `i`.

If you find `a[:, ::-1]` unreadable, you could use [`np.fliplr(a)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) or [`np.flipud(a)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) instead, as Eric suggests.

Comment: `np.flipud(a)` would work in place of `a[:.::-1]` here

Comment: @Eric Not quite. [`np.fliplr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html) would work though. But seeing as they both return views of the data, I find `a[:, ::-1]` more readable, because it uses commonly understood python slice syntax, if with a slight variation allowing a comma-separated list to index different dimensions. `np.fliplr` on the other hand, is a reference to a relatively obscure function (at least, I wasn't familiar with it before your comment). PS: Thanks for catching the typo :-)

Comment: You don't care about the difference between `flipud` and `fliplr` here, since both generate the opposite diagonal

Comment: Yes, you're right, my bad. I didn't realize that `N-j-1-i` is symmetric in `i` and `j`, meaning it doesn't matter whether you flip columns or rows.